# JavaFx how to print text (only) receipt?

Tags: java, javafx, printing

I'm building a point of sale app and i want to print a receipt.
The problem is that with the printer i'm using i can't print any graphics just plain text and all i can find in javafx is to print a node using Print API or use a reporting tool like jasper which both contain graphics.

The receipt i want to produce look like this
[receipt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJ2Ko.jpg)

Thank you for your time

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: I would have guessed one would need to write to a file like "prn:", however see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17505070/printing-reciepts-with-thermal-printer-in-java or http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-print-a-string-using-javax-print-api.html

Comment: Hi @Mat i added an image for the receipt i want to produce ... hope this would give you a clear idea as a start ... i'm trying to build an example now ... thank you.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jps/spec/jpsOverview.fm4.html

Comment: Things like [`Text`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/text/Text.html) and [`Label`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Label.html) are `Node`s; you can print those with the JavaFX print API. There are many other solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print only text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36555291/how-do-i-print-only-text)

Answer (score 5):

This is a note from an `ESC/POS` printer. Although it is possible to print on such a printer using OS printing services, it is preferable to have direct communication with it.

Basically, to print the text is enough to send it to the printer + `\n` (`0x0A`). There are 2 fonts in these printers that can be set to a limited amount of style (double height, double width, bold, italic, underline ...). They also have support for different types of barcodes (by themselves calculating a check sum, if necessary, and plotting the bar code themselves).

Their interface is usually `RS232` or `USB` (Virtual RS - **V**irtual **S**erial **P**ort).

You can use the [javax.comm](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/javacomm/reference/api/javax/comm/package-summary.html) implementation to print on such a printer on java(fx) application. Personally I use [RXTX](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). The printer's communication protocols are usually compatible (at least in the mainstream for text printing) but there is no guarantee of that. So it's nice to work with models you know.

This is an example of printing a note similar to yours on a printer with which I work. The application is usually an `java` application, but there is no problem using such a `javafx` print approach.

```
package posprintdemo;

import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class POSPrintDemo {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String portName = "/dev/ttyS4";
        Integer baudrate = 57600;
        Integer timeout = 1000;

        SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort)CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portName).open(POSPrintDemo.class.getName(), 1000);
        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(baudrate, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
        serialPort.enableReceiveTimeout(timeout);

        try(OutputStream os = serialPort.getOutputStream()) {
            // select double width and height font
            os.write(new byte[] {0x1b, 0x21, 0x31});

            os.write("       AROMA CAFE\n".getBytes());
            os.write("   1211 Green Street\n".getBytes());
            os.write("      New York, NY\n".getBytes());

            // select normal font
            os.write(new byte[] {0x1b, 0x21, 0x01});

            os.write("03-12-2016       1:11PM\n".getBytes());
            os.write("TBL 1            HOST ALISON\n".getBytes());
            os.write("VISA ######8281\n".getBytes());
            os.write("\n".getBytes());
            os.write("QTY  DESC                              AMT\n".getBytes());
            os.write("----------------------------------------------\n".getBytes());
            os.write("1   GINGER CARROT SOUP                   $6.79\n".getBytes());
            os.write("1   HOUSE SALAD                          $7.69\n".getBytes());
            os.write("1   SURF AND RUTF - 1 PERS              $48.79\n".getBytes());
            os.write("1   WINE - GLASS - FIXE                 $11.50\n".getBytes());
            os.write("1   CHOC CAKE                            $6.75\n".getBytes());
            os.write("\n".getBytes());

            // select double width and height font
            os.write(new byte[] {0x1b, 0x21, 0x31});
            os.write("    AMOUNT    $90.52\n".getBytes());

            os.write(new byte[] {0x1b, 0x21, 0x01});
            os.write("\n".getBytes());
            os.write("        SUB-TOTAL           $81.52\n".getBytes());
            os.write("        TAX                  $9.00\n".getBytes());
            os.write("        BALANCE             $90.52\n".getBytes());
            os.write("\n".getBytes());
            os.write("\n".getBytes());
            os.write("\n".getBytes());

            // center text
            os.write(new byte[] {0x1b, 0x61, 0x31}); 

            // set barcode height to 80px
            os.write(new byte[] {0x1d, 0x68, 0x50}); 

            // print CODE39 with text TEST
            os.write(new byte[] {0x1d, 0x6b, 0x45, 0x04, 'T', 'E', 'S', 'T'});
            os.flush();
        }
    }   
}
```

And this is the note received (printed on 57mm wide paper)

[image: this is the note received]

Comment: Hi. I found this today and tried it. It kinda works but not quite, the JVM crashes before the paper is quite finished printing, due to the rxtx dll.

Comment: The library http://rxtx.qbang.org has problems with the latest versions of windows 10 so lately I use https://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/

Answer (score 2):

I would forego the JavaFX print package, and use JPS, specifically the [DocFlavor.STRING.TEXT_PLAIN](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/print/DocFlavor.STRING.html#TEXT_PLAIN) flavor:

```
String receiptText = /* ... */;

PrintService printService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
if (printService != null) {
    Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(receiptText, DocFlavor.STRING.TEXT_PLAIN, null);
    DocPrintJob printJob = printService.createPrintJob();
    printJob.print(doc, null);
}
```

It’s probably best to do the printing in a thread other than the JavaFX application thread.