# How do you print TextArea to a USB Thermal Printer 58mm?(JAVAFX)

Tags: javafx, printing, fxml, thermal-printer, pos

So I'm trying to make a billing system in which I want to print a receipt.I was able to do it with some code that I found online,but the font size is too big to print in the 58mm wide paper.I'm not able to adjust the font size.Any kind of help with this issue will be highly appreciated.Thank You.

Here is The Code :

```
public class PrinterService implements Printable {

    public List<String> getPrinters(){

        DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
        PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

        PrintService printServices[] = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(
                flavor, pras);

        List<String> printerList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(PrintService printerService: printServices){
            printerList.add( printerService.getName());
        }

        return printerList;
    }

    @Override
    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page)
            throws PrinterException {
        if (page > 0) { /* We have only one page, and 'page' is zero-based */
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }

        /*
         * User (0,0) is typically outside the imageable area, so we must
         * translate by the X and Y values in the PageFormat to avoid clipping
         */
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
        /* Now we perform our rendering */

        g.setFont(new Font("Roman", 0, 8));
        g.drawString("Hello world !", 0, 10);

        return PAGE_EXISTS;
    }

    public void printString(String printerName, String text) {

        // find the printService of name printerName
        DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
        PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

        PrintService printService[] = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(
                flavor, pras);
        PrintService service = findPrintService(printerName, printService);

        DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();

        try {

            byte[] bytes;

            // important for umlaut chars
            bytes = text.getBytes("CP437");

            Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(bytes, flavor, null);


            job.print(doc, null);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void printBytes(String printerName, byte[] bytes) {

        DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
        PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

        PrintService printService[] = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(
                flavor, pras);
        PrintService service = findPrintService(printerName, printService);

        DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();

        try {

            Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(bytes, flavor, null);

            job.print(doc, null);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private PrintService findPrintService(String printerName,
                                          PrintService[] services) {
        for (PrintService service : services) {
            if (service.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(printerName)) {
                return service;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

```
@FXML
public void printit(ActionEvent actionEvent)
{
    PrinterService printerService = new PrinterService();

    System.out.println(printerService.getPrinters());

    //print some stuff
    printerService.printString("POS-58-Series", area.getText());
}
```

Comment: Usually with label-printers you program them using their own printer-control-language (like PCL, Postscript, ZPL, Fingerprint, etc) instead of using Java's 2D graphics APIs. Does the printer model you're using come with a Java SDK?

Comment: I'm not familiar with it but have you tried the [printing API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/print/package-summary.html) that comes with JavaFX?

Comment: I've tried the JavaFX printing API and it doesn't work with TextAreas. The printer doesn't come with a Java SDK. It uses ESC/POS commands but even after lots of research, I'm not able to implement in my code, but I think that it is possible.

Comment: Define "doesn't work with `TextArea`s". Maybe something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36555291/how-do-i-print-only-text will help?